# (window).keyup() doesn't work after opening video iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have this piece of code

```
    $(window).keyup(function(event) {
       console.log('hello');
    });
```

it works fine when i'm on the page, but when I open go full view in videoiframe what's on the page so this code doesn't work anymore. I press any key and it does't do anything.

any ideas why keyup function doesn't work in full width video iframe?

thx for any help

Comment: That is because the window object in the video iframe is distinct from that of the page itself :)

Answer (score 1):

Will changing it to $(document) help?

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
       console.log('hello');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> full view in videoiframe

I think you have your answer here.  When the iframe is taking up the whole window, any keyup will occur within the iframe not in the parent document.

Comment: ok, so do you have any idea how to do it? I need to redirect on the other page when I press any key on keybord, when iframe is opened

Comment: Your event capture needs to happen on the iframe so assuming your iframe has an id of myIframe something like this might work:   `$("#myIframe").keyup(function(event){ ... });`  But if you have a flash video loaded into your iframe flash will be capturing the keystrokes.

Comment: it's a embended video from an adult site, so I think it's a flash

Comment: Ok, I think you are going to struggle to achieve what you want.  I doubt this will work but you could try creating a transparent div overlay to sit above your iframe.